# Burning UDF-ISO images with Audio files with audio option

Tags: linux, mkisofs, wodim

What happens if users create a read-only UDF-ISO image file using mkisofs utility, and then
by using wodim utility, include the audio tracks with the image file using either the audio or mode2 XA option?

Comment: If you like an answer, you should describe what you like to know. You are giving far too few information. BTW: if you plan to use `mkisofs`, you seem to have the real software, so why do you like to use the defective `wodim`?